# How to match the text from textBox1 with a certain column to see if it exist?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-express

When I enter a `RegiD` to check-in, it takes me to my form 2 but it happens even if the number is not in my `RegiD` column in my SQL Database. How do it get it to check if the number I entered in my text box is in my SQL Database?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-UHGLPQ8\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test Vol;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MastVolData WHERE [RegiD] =' " + textBox1.Text + "'" , con);

        SqlDataReader dr =  cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read() == true)
            { 
            using (Form2 frm = new Form2(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong I.D! Please try again!");
            }
            textBox1.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a space before the text passed in the WHERE condition. Albeit this should make your query fail I think you need to remove it. Another reason to use parameters instead of string concatenation

Comment: Two tips, that are general in nature and won't solve the problem: 1) SQLExpress is not MySql; 2) **Never** concatenate queries like that, you are wide open my SQL injection attacks.

Comment: No need to fetch all the data from table and determine the exists or not. You just check the condition with If...Exists(Select 1 from your table name where .....). Better than inline query, Prepare a store procedure and return true or false as a output variable

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you need to stop concatenating strings to create SQL statements and start using parameterized queries. Otherwise you are risking [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
**Second**, you need to learn when to use the `using` statement.
**Third**, You need to learn about the `HasRows` property of the `SqlDataReader`.

Your code should end up looking like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // use this local variable to prevent keeping sql connection and an active data reader longer than neccessary
        var hasRows = false; 

        // You should really get the connection string from your web.config file, I left it hard coded so that you can test.
        var connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-UHGLPQ8\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test Vol;Integrated Security=True";

        // Use the using statement for any local variable that implements the IDisposable interface
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MastVolData WHERE [RegiD] = @RegiD;", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RegiD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                con.Open();
                using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    hasRows = dr.HasRows;
                }
            }
        }

        // Now that your sql connection is closed and disposed, you can use ShowDialog
        if (hasRows)
        {
            using (Form2 frm = new Form2(textBox1.Text))
            {
                frm.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong I.D! Please try again!");
        }

        textBox1.Clear();
    }
}
```